# Cant seem to set the Environment Path for JDK ver 13 correctly

Tags: java, path, sdk, environment

Installed jDK-13.0.2 on Win10; set Path to javac as required and cmd does not recognize the command, but if I paste the same path directly to command line in CMD, the command and compiler work fine. I am operating in Admin mode. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Show stuff......

Comment: Welcome to SO! I think you could improve your chances of getting an answer with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Explain *exactly* what you did, and we will help you figure out what you did wrong.  Note that there are many, many explanations of how to set the PATH variable ... so yet another explanation would be redundant.